# bubble sort function implementation not working

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with bubble sort. I'm sorting an array of 8 numbers in descending order; however, when printing to screen, the first number is not in the array. it is like is an out of bound error, or printing some memory content. Any help appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sortArray(int nums[]);
void printArray(int nums[]);


int main()
{
    int nums[8] = {3, 6, -19, 5, 5, 0, -2, 99};

    sortArray(nums); 

    printArray(nums);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void sortArray(int nums[])
{
     bool swap;
     int temp;

     do
     {
         swap = false;
         for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
         {
                 if(nums[i] < nums[i+1])
                 {
                       temp = nums[i];
                       nums[i] = nums[i+1];
                       nums[i+1] = temp;
                       swap = true;
                 }
         }
     }while(swap);
}

void printArray(int nums[])
{
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
             cout << nums[i] << ", ";
     }
     cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing an element beyond the end of the array with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
         {
                 if(nums[i] < nums[i+1])
```

If `i` goes up to 7, `i+1` goes out of bounds.

By the way, you should look into using `std::vector` instead of plain arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First C++ course? I'm a TA again.

int array, with size = 8, i.e. index 0 to 7.

In your for(int i=0; i<8; i++) you're trying to access nums[i+1], what happens when i = 7? Access nums[8], right?

Furthermore, this is NOT a bubble sort, its closed to, but not actually. Read your textbook again.

Answer (score 0):

```
     for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
             if(nums[i] < nums[i+1])
             {
                   temp = nums[i];
                   nums[i] = nums[i+1];
                   nums[i+1] = temp;
                   swap = true;
             }
     }
```

When `i` is 7, you're accessing out of bounds on the `i+1`s.