# What is wrong with my Bubble Sort code?

Tags: c++

```
void bubbleSort(int ar1[10], int logicalSize)
{
   int tempHolder = 0; 
   for (int i = logicalSize; i >= 2; i--)
   {
      for(int i2 = 0; i2 < logicalSize-i2; i++)
      {
         if (ar1[i2 + 1] < ar1[i2])
         {
            tempHolder = ar1[i2]; 
            ar1[i2] = ar1[i2 + 1]; 
            ar1[i2 + 1] = tempHolder; 
         }

      }
   }
   cout << "The array in sorted order: " << endl; 
   for(int i2 = 0; i2 <= 10; i2++)
   {
      cout << ar1[i2] << endl;
   }
} 

int main () 
{
   int arry1[10]; 
   arry1[0] = 8;
   arry1[1] = 56;
   arry1[2] = 4;
   arry1[3] = 25;
   arry1[4] = 45;
   arry1[5] = 92;
   arry1[6] = 11;
   arry1[7] = 1;
   arry1[8] = 78;
   arry1[9] = 66;
   arry1[10] = 24;

   cout << "The array in its original order: " << endl; 
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
   {
      cout << arry1[i] << endl;
   }

   bubbleSort(arry1, 11);

   cout << "The array in sorted order: " << endl; 
   for(int i2 = 0; i2 <= 10; i2++)
   {
      cout << arry1[i2] << endl;
   }


   return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to get my bubble sort to work. The code looks fine and my array appears to be set up properly. Can anyone help me get this to work? Are my loops in mt function set up incorrectly? Or is it what happens within the loops that is causing my errors to occur?

Comment: Can you describe what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: This question is ridiculous. Don't use stackoverflow for a debugger.

Comment: Tempted to close as duplicate of [bubble sort function implementation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221281/bubble-sort-function-implementation-not-working)...

Comment: While your here, let me save you some time in the future; initialize an array like this - `int arry1[10] = {8, 56, 4, 25, 45, 92, 11, 1, 78, 66};`

Comment: @andre yes he need to read arrays first.

Answer (score 1):

1. You've got buffer overflow (11 elements instead of 10)
2. You need to increment i2 in `for(int i2 = 0; i2 < logicalSize-i2; i++)`, like this: `for(int i2 = 0; i2 < logicalSize-i2; i2++)`
3. You need to iterate until `< 10` not `<= 10`.
4. `bubbleSort(arry1, 11)` should be `bubbleSort(arry1, 10)`
5. You may want to have your `for` loops like (a poor version of bubble sort):

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < logicalSize; i++)
    {
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < logicalSize; i2++)
        {
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That was such a simple mistake. But now it isn't actually sorting correctly and its adding on to my logical size of the array too. Any ideas with how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You declare the array for 10 members, so you have index 0 to 9. so `arry1[10]=24;` overflows the array. There were some logical mistake in your  `bubbleSort`  function which makes your loops infinite.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int ar1[], int logicalSize)
{
   int tempHolder = 0;    //logical mistake , which makes your loop infinite
   for (int i = 0; i < logicalSize; i++)
   {
      for(int i2 = 0; i2 < logicalSize-1; i2++)
      {
         if (ar1[i2 + 1] < ar1[i2])
         {
            tempHolder = ar1[i2];
            ar1[i2] = ar1[i2 + 1];
            ar1[i2 + 1] = tempHolder;
         }

      }
   }
   cout << "The array in sorted order: " << endl;
   for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
   {
      cout << ar1[i2] << endl;
   }
}

int main ()
{
   int arry1[10];
   arry1[0] = 8;
   arry1[1] = 56;
   arry1[2] = 4;
   arry1[3] = 25;
   arry1[4] = 45;
   arry1[5] = 92;
   arry1[6] = 11;
   arry1[7] = 1;
   arry1[8] = 78;
   arry1[9] = 66;
  // arry1[10] = 24;  //array overflow

   cout << "The array in its original order: " << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      cout << arry1[i] << endl;
   }

   bubbleSort(arry1, 10);

   cout << "The array in sorted order: " << endl;
   for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
   {
      cout << arry1[i2] << endl;
   }


   return 0;
}
```